# Apache: is it possible to delegate access control to executable?

Tags: apache

Is it possible to make apache call another executable or script to check for access restrictions?

What I'm trying to do is implement a way of calling a script that can check for restrictions others than just the file system file's permissions (for example: checking if the request includes a valid PHP session cookie) and telling apache in some way that it must return a 403 error code if the access to the requested file is not allowed (for example: by returning an exit code other than 0).

In the past I have used PHP scripts that handle requests for image files and take care of access restrictions. The problem is that I had to set all headers programmatically also, which is not trivial (for example: if you want to support 304 responses, the code must check the modification time of the file and compare it with the time stated in the response, or check "etags", etc). I would like to find a way to avoid all that hassle and just let apache handle the "headers part" and another script/binary to handle the "access part".

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [prg: `RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg), and disallow access with a `RewriteRule` af the program returns 'NULL'. If you are going to use a php script for it, you'd open `php://stdin`, read an incoming `Cookie:` header from it, and determine whether it is a session you want to allow. The problem with checking those sessions in vanilla php session is you'll almost *have* to start that session to figure that out: make sure you have all possible class definitions needed for it loaded or autoloadable, call `session_id('the id you found in the cookie');`, `session_start()`, examine `$_SESSION`, and write `session_write_close()` again. There lies all kind of danger (broken sessions if your classes aren't loaded correctly, errors if your php script unexpectedly dies, etc.).

If you have your Apache server under control, I would prefer [mod-xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/): open a php script, the php scripts sets the location of the image to deliver, and `mod-xsendfile` does the rest, including etags, modificiation times, etc. You can then even store your 'restricted' content outside of the document root if you like (but check if you what you deliver is of course content you *want* to deliver, not some random file on your disk).

Comment: Excellent! For what I can get from the supplied links, it seems that both options would help me achieve the desired result. The explanation is also very good :-) I think that mod-xsendfile would be the safer and easiest option in this case.